# How to keep the cummulative polygons in time manager for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I use time manager for a polygon layers with dates and it works. I would like to see the cummulative addition of my polygons. So I have 4 periods I want the poylgons from 1900-1950 to be added to the new ones in 1950-2000 etc in the next time step. How can I perform that or does another open source tool exist for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to check **Accumulate features** in time manager *Settings*. Its last option in the layer row.

[image]