# Time Manager Plugin QGIS

Tags: timemanager

I am using the Time Manager plugin in QGIS and the data points from the CSV shapefile with animation to display the data points for a month at a time, is there a way that I can have the data points remain on the map and not disappear - So it's like the data points are building into a sort of heat map

Instead of showing the (month) data points and then disappearing and the showing the next (month) of data points and so on

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please, improve the title of the post to something more descriptive. Your question is not exactly a duplicate of: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240602/how-to-keep-the-cummulative-polygons-in-time-manager-for-qgis, but very similar. I have just added an answer, but also voting to close your post as duplicate. If you think that it is not a duplicate, please improve your question to express why you did not find the answer to the previous post helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Settings of the Time Manager plugin, check on the *Accumulate features* field for that layer.

[image: 1]

---

If you want to show the features to some specific time, create a new field in the layer with that timestamp and then set that field in the *End* field of the Settings.

[image: 2]